# Outlook : How to get reference of (EntryID, optional & required attendee) newly added item in Appointment.Write event handler

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, mapi

I want to capture the information of new created appointment item, For that I hook the event with NewInstpector window & again hook the Write event. I am also using standard outlook item wrapper(from msdn).

The problem is inside the Item_Write event handler  I get the reference of new item however some properties are coming as NULL. For e.g. EntryID, Optional attendees.

The value for EntryID might be null because item is not yet witten on the exchange server, so the question is how to capture the EntryID of newly created appiointment item

Atul Sureka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EntryID` is not set until the item is saved or sent, because it isn't added to the store otherwise.

You will need to do either of those things before you can read the entry ID.